# Toggle Javascript functions on same button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nav that pops out from the side and was wondering how it would come out then go back in using the same button. It's probably quite easy but I am unsure of how to do it.

The side nav and normal nav

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mainSidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mainSidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}

function navButton(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```html
<div id="mainSidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">page 1</a>
  <a href="#">page 2</a>
  <a href="#">page 3</a>
  <a href="#">page 4</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light flex-row-reverse"> <span class="h1 navbar-brand mb-0">Navbar</span>
      <form class="justify-content-end">
        <div class="navButton" onclick="navButton(this);openNav();closeNav();">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

and the button that is supposed to control everything is the "navButton"

Comment: Look like we need some of your CSS too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the function just check if x has class change, if it does call closeNav() and remove class change, and do opposite for the else case.

```
function navButton(x) {
  if(x.classList.contains("change")){
     closeNav();
     x.classList.remove("change");

  }else{
     openNav();
     x.classList.add("change");
  }
}
```

also you only need to call navButton() from onclick of .navButton.

```
    <div class="navButton" onclick="navButton(this)">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a class 'opened' if opened sidebar in your open/close functions and use JQuery like this:

```
$('.navButton').on('click', function() {
     if($('#mainSidenav').hasClass('opened')) {
          closeNav(); //remove class opened to mainSidenav in this method
     } else {
          openNav(); //open class opened to mainSidenav in this method
     }  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of the code, I implemented whatever I know like instead of using inline styles just add a class to do the width change! Then the div you create for the icon, can just be made using an awesome library called [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/),  Apart from this added some basic styling to make the layout and the demo look better.

Please let me know if there are any issues!

```js
function toggleNav() {
  document.getElementById("mainSidenav").classList.toggle("open");
  document.getElementById("main").classList.toggle("open");
}

function navButton(x) {
  x.children[0].classList.toggle('fa-bars');
  x.children[0].classList.toggle('fa-close');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#mainSidenav {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#mainSidenav a {
  display: list-item;
}

#mainSidenav {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navButton div {
  height: 3px;
}

#main.open {
  margin-left: 250px;
}

#main {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#mainSidenav.open {
  width: 250px;
}

#mainSidenav {
  width: 0px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
}

.mb-0 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="mainSidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">page 1</a>
  <a href="#">page 2</a>
  <a href="#">page 3</a>
  <a href="#">page 4</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light flex-row-reverse"> <span class="h1 navbar-brand mb-0">Navbar</span>
      <form class="justify-content-end">
        <div class="navButton" onclick="navButton(this);toggleNav();">
          <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </form>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```